# Modx - Multiple contexts on one domain

Tags: modx, modx-revolution

I've a Modx site running. Now i want to get some resources like modx-generated javascript files. It is possible to put these in the web context, but than it can be seen by all users.

So i created a new context named "Resources" (key: res), gave it Load-Only permissions and created a resource in it. I've also initialize it in the `index.php` file:

```
$modx->initialize('web');
$modx->initialize('res');
```

But when i try to access the resource, it doesn't work.

Did i missed something?

Answer (score 0):

Calling `modX::initialize()` twice will not work as it checks for state.

Either remove the first call to initailise the `web` state or write a plugin and use [modX::switchContext()](http://rtfm.modx.com/revolution/2.x/developing-in-modx/other-development-resources/class-reference/modx/modx.switchcontext)

Comment: But when i remove the first call, the web resources are not available anymore. I want to do them both, or make some resources hidden for some people but available direct on the web.

Comment: Have you looked into modx acl? More specifically resource groups?